# move_uploaded_file affects JPG image quality(colors)

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload an image in a folder using the move_uploaded_file() function. The image usually is a JPG.

The problem is that the moving process somehow affects the image quality. To me mor eprecises, the colors are not the same between the file that i want to upload and the uploaded file.

So far i think the problem lies withing the move_uploaded_file() function, as the colors of the temp file are correct.

Here is my code and the images before and after the upload(the top one is before uploading and the bottom one ois after upload).

This kind of behaviour isn't accepted as the results need to be print ready.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if (!$this->request->data['TplElement']['file']) {
            $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['original_id'] = 0;
            $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['filepath'] = NULL;
            $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['filepath_hires'] = NULL;
            $this->TplElementImage->save($tplElementImage);
        }
        else {
            //create the directory
            $path = APP.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'uploads'.DS.'templates'.DS.$tplElement['TplElement']['tpl_asset_page_id'].DS.$tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['tpl_element_id'].DS.$elementID;

            if ($this->make_path($path.DS.'dummy.txt')) {
                $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['original_file_name'] = $this->request->data['TplElement']['file']['name'];
                $filename = session_id().'_'.time().'_'.$tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['original_file_name'];
                if ($this->request->data['TplElement']['file']['size'] > 0) {
                    if(move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['TplElement']['file']['tmp_name'], $path.DS.$filename)) {
                        $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['filepath'] = '/uploads' . '/' . 'templates' . '/' . $tplElement['TplElement']['tpl_asset_page_id'] . '/' . $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['tpl_element_id'] . '/' . $elementID . '/' . $filename;

                        $imageSize = getimagesize($path . DS . $filename);

                        $imageWidth = $imageSize[0];
                        $imageHeight = $imageSize[1];

                        $zoom = 1;

                        $imageWidthMm = $imageWidth * 25.4 / 200;
                        $imageHeightMm = $imageHeight * 25.4 / 200;

                        $inBlockImageHeight = $imageHeight * $blockWidth / $imageWidth;
                        $inBlockImageWidth = $imageWidth * $blockHeight / $imageHeight;
                        if ($inBlockImageHeight < $blockHeight || $inBlockImageWidth < $blockWidth) {
                            $zoom = max($blockHeight / $imageHeightMm, $blockWidth / $imageWidthMm);
                        }

                        if ($zoom > 1) {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Image too small'));
                            $this->redirect('/tpl_asset_pages/edit/' . $tplElement['TplElement']['tpl_asset_page_id']);
                            return;
                        }

                        $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['zoom'] = $zoom;
                        $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['original_width'] = $imageWidth;
                        $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['original_height'] = $imageHeight;
                        $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['top'] = 0;
                        $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['left'] = 0;
                        $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['original_id'] = 0;
                        $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['filepath_hires'] = NULL;
                        $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['max_zoom_value'] = $this->ElementImage->GetMaxZoom($imageWidth, $imageHeight, $blockWidth, $blockHeight);

                        if ($this->TplElementImage->save($tplElementImage)) {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('File successfully saved'));
                        } else {
                            $this->Session->setFlash("Unable to save data");
                        }
                    }else{
                        $this->Session->setFlash("Unable to move file");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ($this->request->data['TplElement']['file']['size'] > 0) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash("Unable to save uploaded file");
                    }
                    else {
                        $tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['filepath'] = NULL;
                        $this->TplElementImage->save($tplElementImage);
                        $this->Session->setFlash("Unable to save uploaded file");
                    }

                }
            }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to create folder');
            }
        }
        $this->redirect('/tpl_asset_pages/edit/'.$tplElement['TplElement']['tpl_asset_page_id']);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or moving the file after upload, you are either post processing it on your server or your have a color profile attached to it.  You need to show your ... stuff code

Comment: i've edited the question and added the rest of the code. There is no processing done on the image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed using Imagick to write the file.

```
$img = new Imagick($this->request->data['TplElement']['file']['tmp_name']);
$img->setImageFormat(substr(strrchr($tplElementImage['TplElementImage']['original_file_name'],'.'),1));
//stuff
if($img->writeImage($path.DS.$filename)) {
    //stuff
}
//stuff
```